# Table resize problem in two coloumn format

Tags: tables, xetex

I am trying to resize the table in single column and my table is very big and not fitting in the document.

This my latex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{acl2016}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.5}
\definecolor{darkpurple}{rgb}{0.4,0.0,0.4}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{darkorange}{rgb}{0.5,0.45,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.5,0.0}
\definecolor{darkergreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.4,0.0}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,1.0}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.8,1.0,0.8}
\definecolor{lightred}{rgb}{1.0,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{lightyellow}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,0.8}
\definecolor{lightorange}{rgb}{1.0,0.9,0.8}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.96,0.97,0.98}
\definecolor{brilliantlavender}{rgb}{0.96, 0.73, 1.0}

% define notes
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\Note}[3]{\sethlcolor{#2}\hl{[\textbf{#1}: #3]}}
\renewcommand{\Note}[3]{}

\newcommand{\ryan}[1]{\Note{ryan}{brilliantlavender}{#1}}
\newcommand{\arun}[1]{\Note{arun}{lightorange}{#1}}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\Note{todo}{red}{#1}}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xMapsto}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0599{\Mapstofill@}{#1}{#2}}
\def\Mapstofill@{\arrowfill@{\Mapstochar\Relbar}\Relbar\Rightarrow}
\makeatother

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\mal}{Meera}
\newfontfamily {\tam}{Lohit Tamil}

\def\figref#1{Figure~\ref{fig:#1}}
\def\figlabel#1{\label{fig:#1}\label{p:#1}}
\def\Tabref#1{Table~\ref{tab:#1}}
\def\tabref#1{Table~\ref{tab:#1}}
\def\tablabel#1{\label{tab:#1}\label{p:#1}}
\def\Secref#1{Section~\ref{sec:#1}}
\def\secref#1{Section~\ref{sec:#1}}
\def\seclabel#1{\label{sec:#1}\label{p:#1}}
\def\eqref#1{Eq.~\ref{eqn:#1}}
\def\eqrefn#1{\ref{eqn:#1}}
\def\eqsref#1#2{Eqs.~\ref{eqn:#1}-\ref{eqn:#2}}
\def\eqlabel#1{\label{eqn:#1}}
\def\subsp#1{P_{\mbox{{\scriptsize\rm #1}}}}

% To expand the titlebox for more authors, uncomment
% below and set accordingly.
% \addtolength\titlebox{.5in}    

\renewcommand{\vec}{\boldsymbol}   % optional
\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

%space hacks
% save for camera ready
\newcommand{\saveforCR}[1]{}
```

This is my code for the table

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|lll|}
        \hline
        ~                 & Surface form                    &  Underlying form                     \\ \hline
        Insertion         & മഴയാണ് maḻa\texttt{y}āṇ         & മഴ ആണ് maḻa āṇ                       \\ 
        Deletion          & കണ്ടില്ല kaṇṭilla               & കണ്ടു  ഇല്ല   kaṇṭ\texttt{u}illa    \\ 
        Substitution      & ഇഷ്ടമാണ് iṣṭ\texttt{am}āṇ       & ഇഷ്ടം  ആണ്  iṣṭa\texttt{ṁ} āṇ        \\ 
        Vowel lengthening & മുനീന്ദ്രൻ  mun\texttt{ī}ndran  & മുനി  ഇന്ദ്രൻ           \\ muni indran  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This the  table size I get [image]

How to resize it properly?

Comment: It's not really a TeX question, there really isn't room for a three column table with long single line texts unless you set it impossibly small, just use some other format, either a list instead of a table, or having twice as many rows with the latin alphabet transcriptions on every other row instead of to the right, or anything else that fits.

Comment: What can I do there ?

Comment: as I say you need to decide what layout you want, especially as I can not read the script I can not suggests anything. If you said what layout you wanted someone could tell you the tex markup.

Comment: That means, it is impossible to align the table ???

Comment: It is aligned. it is just too big,  You could change lll to `p{.3\columnwidth}p{.3\columnwidth}p{.3\columnwidth}` or some other length then it will be narrower but probably look horrible. I repeat: if you said what you wanted the output to look like someone would tell you how to do that. Jjust saying "align the table" does not mean anything.

Comment: I have changed the question

Comment: For start try to "align" table over two columns: for this use `\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}`

Comment: Where does one obtain the `acl2016` style from?

Comment: http://acl2016.org/files/acl2016.zip

Comment: What if you print the table *before* the text splits into two columns?